# how can I fix this error when allocating memory?

Tags: c++, casting, malloc

the code below has an error please help me how can I fix it. I'm beginner in C++.

```
int main(int    argc,   char    **argv)
{
image=malloc(3*1450*900*sizeof(char));      /*  to  ALLOCATE    MEMORY  required    to  SAVE    the file    */
    some thing else....}
```

> The error is: a value of type "void*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char*"

Comment: In C++ you should not use `malloc`, not even for simple types like arrays of characters. Use `new[]` instead.

Comment: As for why you get an error, it's because C++ is, unlike C (where `malloc comes from) is more strongly typed. You can't just go around and use pointers to different types interchangeably. And `malloc` returns a `void*` which is a generic pointer in C, but C++ doesn't really have such a concept. Yes you can still use `void*`, but then you need to explicitly cast to or from it.

Comment: Actually, you only need to cast *from* it.  Any pointer will convert *to* `void *`without a cast.

Comment: It is not good advice to use `new[]`.  Use `std::array` if fixed length or `std::vector` if you are going to resize the allocated memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's clear as you see in error report!
you should cast every thing at the other side of "=" operator to (char*)!

> image=(char*)malloc(3*1450*900*sizeof(char));

Answer (score 5):

First, In C++ you should be using `new / new[]` and `delete / delete[]` instead of `malloc()`.

An even better way would be to use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/): `std::vector<char> image(3*1450*900);`

---

If you really would need to use `malloc()` in C++, you need to cast the return value (`malloc()` returns a `void*`):

```
image = (char*)malloc(3*1450*900*sizeof(char));
```

And of course, always check the return value before continuing.

Comment: Or, better still:  `std::vector<char> image(3*1450*900);`

Comment: @MartinBonner - Yes, that would be another possibility.

Comment: `operator new` and `operator delete` are rarely used in C++ code, if you aren't writing your own allocator. Maybe you meant the `new` expression (e.g. `image = new char[1234];`) although that is an outdated technique

Comment: I think `std::array<char,3*1450*900> image;` is more suitable.

Comment: @SHR You'd have to watch out for stack overflow though , this is nearly a 4MB array and some typical systems default to 2MB of stack or less

Comment: @M.M - yes, of course. I'll update the answer. Thanks.

Comment: -1 For giving only a code sample for malloc.  It's a quick-and-dirty solution that'll squelch the error, but the wrong solution.   If the OP said that using malloc was necessary (say, for compat with some other lib) then this would be an appropriate answer.  I'll change to an upvote if your “the way this is usually done in C++” part is moved to be first & foremost.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson - You're right. I started with malloc() because the OP asked how to fix the call. Answer updated.

Answer (score 4):

### Why it doesn't work and a quick fix

The reason your code doesn't work is, that `malloc()` returns a `void*` which cannot be implicitly converted to a `char*`. Therefore, it is said that `malloc()` is not type-safe. You can cast the returned pointer explicitly by writing `(char*)malloc(3*1450*900)` but this is kinda ugly. (BTW `sizeof(char)` is always 1.)

### A more modern approach

In modern C++ you should do memory allocations using containers like `std::vector<T>`. Also: try to avoid global variables outside functions and classes. Here's what I would write:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<char> image( 3*1450*900 ); // automatically fills with zeros.
}
```

This has the advantage, that memory management is done automatically. The allocated memory will be freed when the `image` object is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using C++, you should instead be creating your arrays with `new[]` and deleting them with `delete[]`.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    image = new char[3 * 1450 * 900];
    // ... some code here? ...
    // When you're finished with image:
    delete[] image;
    // ... some code here? ...
    return 0;
}
```

You don't need `sizeof` if you're using the `new[]` or `new` operators, but even so, I want to mention that `sizeof(char)` is *always* equal to 1.

If you are using C++11 (you should be!), then it might be more appropriate to declare image as a `unique_ptr<char[]>` to prevent memory leaks caused by improper exception handling or simply forgetting the `delete[]`.

Comment: That was the answer for the 1980s... these days it is `unique_ptr<char[]> image = new char[3 * 1450 * 900];` or `vector<char> image(3 * 1450 * 900);`

Comment: @M.M Is this a joke or a serious response? I don't know a nicer way to put this but I honestly can't tell.

Comment: Serious response. Your suggestion is prone to error because an exception may be thrown before the `delete[]` is reached, among other reasons

Comment: I see your concerns, but since this is happening at the beginning of the `main` function, an uncaught exception would terminate the program anyway. The same goes for `unique_ptr`: when `main` is left, the program will have terminated. (Of course the story may be a little different if threads are being used, but that is a different kettle of fish).

Comment: I've added the former half of your comment to the answer because I feel it's relevant in the general case, but I've left out the `vector` since the name `image` suggests that it should never expand or contract.

Comment: OK. It should be `unique_ptr<char[]>`, to indicate that array deletion will be used.

Comment: @M.M Post your own answer using `unique_ptr` please.  Score_Under's answer is not incorrect, and still applicable (consistency is always a good idea, and it's still likely that a dev may be working on a codebase that doesn't already use unique_ptr).

Comment: @Score_Under `vector` is entirely correct and idiomatic in C++ even if resizing is never required. Better yet, it's exception-safe and guaranteed to be work in any C++ compiler. C++11 isn't everywhere, yet...

Comment: @M.M Unrelated to the question at hand but I want to make it clear why I thought your response might have been a joke at first. First was "That was the answer for the 1980s", which seems like a comical exaggeration, and second is giving two slightly more complex solutions without explaining why (which reminded me a little of the "How do I add 2 numbers in Javascript" / "there's a jQuery module for that" parody). Those two things together made me wonder if the comment was a joke.

Comment: Right. Bare `new` might seem simple at first but when you take into account all the ensuing issues, it's actually a lot easier in a real program to use the `unique_ptr` or container versions (even if you use a resizable container when you aren't planning to resize).

Comment: Agreed.  These days beginners shouldn't use new at all, and experts only rarely.